# Cómo añadir el link de edición de respuesta en google sheets solo si cumple una condición

Tags: javascript, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-forms

Tengo el siguiente código que añade el link de edición de la respuestas de un formulario, pero precisamente ese es el problema, cada vez que se edita algo vuelve a sobreescribir el link gastandome la cuota diaria... Me interesa añadir el link siempre y cuando la columna 3 *urlCol = 3* no tenga escrito en su celda la palabra *true* si la tiene escrita no sobreescribir 'añadir' el link. Sé que es con *if* pero no sé cómo validar el texto de una columna en google sheets.

```js
function assignEditUrls() {
var form = FormApp.openById('');
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('respuestas1');
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var urlCol = 3;
var responses = form.getResponses();
var timestamps = [], urls = [], resultUrls = [];
for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
timestamps.push(responses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0));
urls.push(responses[i].getEditResponseUrl());
}
for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
resultUrls.push([data[j][0]?urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))]:'']);
}
sheet.getRange(2, urlCol, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls);
}
```

Comment: Según leo, el núcleo del problema es este: *Me interesa añadir el link siempre y cuando la columna 3 urlCol = 3 no tenga escrito en su celda la palabra true si la tiene escrita no sobreescribir 'añadir' el link. Sé que es con if pero no sé cómo validar el texto de una columna en google sheets.* Pero en el código no veo que hagas nada de eso. Además, estarías recorriendo toda la hoja cada vez. ¿No es mejor escuchar la fila que haya sido modificada, hacer la comparación y modificar esa sola fila? Quizá es eso lo que está agotando la cuota, que lees todas las filas cada vez.

Comment: Sea como sea, falta información contextual que ayude a entender el problema. Si tu hoja está ligada a un formulario, puedes usar los eventos de formulario para modificar la sola fila de la respuesta ingresada en el formulario, si es una hoja independiente puedes escuchar la edición de esa hoja, revisa métodos como `onChange` en la documentación y los tipos de trigger que se pueden disparar desde formularios o desde hojas.